# Why does call to midiInGetDevCaps from Visual Basic truncate device name?

Tags: vb.net, marshalling

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community on Windows 10.

I want my Visual Basic program to write the name of my one MIDI device (which is "Oxygen 49") to the debug console. My code below works, but the "9" doesn't appear in the name string (it's just "Oxygen 4"). Using the debugger confirms that, upon return from the call to `midiInGetDevCaps`, the "9" isn't in the structure. I replaced the String with four Longs and unpacked the bytes individually. When I did that, the complete name was there. Thus, I suspect it is a problem with how I am marshaling my String (or, maybe, the problem is I am expecting unmanaged code to be able to modify a String, and that's not allowed?).

Can anyone help me understand why the name comes back missing the last character?

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Public Declare Function midiInGetDevCaps Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "midiInGetDevCapsA" _
    (ByVal uDeviceID As Integer, ByRef lpCaps As MIDIINCAPS, ByVal uSize As Integer) _
    As Integer

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
    Public Structure MIDIINCAPS
        Dim wMid As Int16 ' Manufacturer ID
        Dim wPid As Int16 ' Product ID
        Dim vDriverVersion As Integer ' Driver version
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=32)> Dim szPname As String
        'Dim szPname As Long ' Replace the line above with these four and
        'Dim b2 As Long      ' unpack them. The correct name is returned.
        'Dim b3 As Long
        'Dim b4 As Long
        Dim dwSupport As Integer ' Reserved
    End Structure

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles Me.Load

        Dim InCaps As New MIDIINCAPS

        midiInGetDevCaps(0, InCaps, Len(InCaps))
        Debug.Print(InCaps.szPname)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**UPDATE**

I don't know why, nor have I tested this much, but changing this line:

```vb
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=32)> Dim szPname As String
```

to this:

```vb
<VBFixedString(32), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=32)> Dim szPname As String
```

makes `midiInGetDevCaps` return the full name.

Anyone know why it works?